# apache redirecting entire site

Tags: apache, apache2

I have this site that needs to be inside our secure network that my work uses. I would like to redirect the users when they are trying to access the page to this secure path. For example,  If someone tries to access `mydomain.com/pictures` I want apache to take them to `https://mycompanysecure.com/,ThisSite=mydomain.com/pictures,SSL`. I want the whole entire site to be redirected like the example above. I think I need to use wildcards, but I am really new on Apache and I don't know how to do this. I want also want also to make it the default when my app launches it always stay like that. So far I was only able to do this with the root path.

This is what I have so far:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mydomain.com
   redirect / https://yourcompany.net/,ThisSite=mydomain.com,SSL
</VirtualHost *:80>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture and substitute the URL by using RedirectMatch:

```
   RedirectMatch ^/(.*) https://yourcompany.net/,ThisSite=mydomain.com/$1,SSL
```

Comment: That's odd, it shouldn't be susceptible to looping since you should be editing the port http vhost for mydomain.com and redirecting to an https vhost on yourcompany.net.

Comment: I don't know either. I'll have to play around some more to figure it out. It might be the program I'm using. I'll still give you the right answer check mark.